# Organize templates for an app with require.js - cross origin request in a mobile browser

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, requirejs

I'm building an app using phonegap, jqm, underscore and backbone. To avoid having all my templates used by underscore.js in the index.html I want to use require.js.

Testing on a local machine I run into this error:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load file:///[...]loginTemplate.html. Cross origin requests are only supported for HTTP.
```

How does a web-container on a mobile device handle these requests for the template file? Is this regarded as a http-request or a file request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the request is transfered to a http-request on mobile phones.